# Tokenize String for words including non-word characters

Tags: javascript, regex, tokenize

I want to tokenize Twitter messages including hash- and cash-tags. A correct example for tokenization would be like this:

```
"Bought $AAPL today,because of the new #iphone".match(...);
>>>> ['Bought', '$AAPL', 'today', 'because', 'of', 'the', 'new', '#iphone']
```

I tried several regexes for this task, ie:

```
"Bought $AAPL today,because of the new #iphone".match(/\b([\w]+?)\b/g);
>>>> ['Bought', 'AAPL', 'today', 'because', 'of', 'the', 'new', 'iphone']
```

and

```
"Bought $AAPL today,because of the new #iphone".match(/\b([\$#\w]+?)\b/g);
>>>> ['Bought', 'AAPL', 'today', 'because', 'of', 'the', 'new', 'iphone']
```

and

```
"Bought $AAPL today,because of the new #iphone".match(/[\b^#\$]([\w]+?)\b/g);
>>>> ['$AAPL', '#iphone']
```

Which regex could I use, to include the leading sharp or dollar sign in the tokens?

Comment: @Ejay: sometimes people use `.`, `!`, `?` as well

Comment: Sorry had deleted my comment before reading yours :) `"Bought $AAPL today,because of the new #iphone".match(/[^ ,\!\?\.]+/g)`

Comment: Actually can you please post samples of the possible strings? Edit: you've the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about obvious

```
"Bought $AAPL today,because of the new #iphone".match(/[$#]*\w+/g)
// ["Bought", "$AAPL", "today", "because", "of", "the", "new", "#iphone"]
```

?

PS: `[$#]*` might be replaced with `[$#]?`, not sure about exact requirements.

Comment: This works, I thought using word delimiters (`\b`) would be in a way more save, but I can't think of an edge case right now where this applies, so your solution should work totally perfect, thanks.